# How to give extra character between text by css. Css is applied but showing wrong result

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying t display my text on screen. In this I am using one css to make color change.

Here is my code

```
var myStar =   '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">*</span>'
myStr = "Hello"+ "<br>" + myStar+ '(myValue)';
```

But text is not appearing properly. Instead to display actual text it is displaying like this.

```
*</span>(myValue)" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-text-default x-form-textarea"  role="textbox" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-multiline="true" aria-required="false" autocomplete="off">
```

It should only display

Hello

*(myValue)

Here is my actual js code where I am using this.

```
xtype: 'textArea',
height:70,
fieldLabel: '<div>'+myStr+'</div>',
name: myStr,
labelAlign: 'right',
margin:5,
labelWidth:180,
value: "some Value",
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you share the entirety of the relevant javascript? The portion you've included in your question is just manipulating strings - it doesn't actually *do* anything regarding the `<span>`. We'll need a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help.

Comment: The section you've now added is still just an incomplete snippet of pseudo-code. Please refer to my link from the previous comment: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i don't know what's your problem. but it works for me.

Comment: Are you sure you actually want to make use of two different variables (`myStar` and `myStr`)? And what is the actual **problem** you're facing -- you don't want the extra class / aria information there?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Actual problem is It should display only "Hello * Value" but instead of that it displaying what i mentioned in code. I actually have doubt for the div which i am using as a `fieldLabel`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to produce the required result by using your code provided.
Here is what I did.

In my HTML file, I created a div element with some id like this.

```
<div id = "someId">
</div>
```

Then I my JS file, I simply used your code to construct `myStr`.

```
var myStar =   '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">*</span>'
myStr = "Hello"+ "<br>" + myStar+ '(myValue)';
```

and I fnally, I used `HTML DOM innerHTML Property` to set HTML content of that `div`.

```
document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML = myStr;
```

here is a working code.

```js
var myStar =   '<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">*</span>'
myStr = "Hello"+ "<br>" + myStar+ '(myValue)';
document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML = myStr;
```

```html
<div id = "someId">
</div>
```

Comment: i think the DOM manipulation in this question is done using some js library, see question as some parameters are provided. No Doubt, your answer produces exact result, but it may not be helpful for the person in this case.

Comment: I think the same. Actually,  the user had asked only what I gave an answer to initially. The person updated his question later.

Comment: oh ok, this definitely may help. Hope the person can achieve his solution through your correct answer.